# SQL - Using a prepared statement for the FROM clause?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

Is it possible to use a prepared statement for the `FROM` clause?

I'm trying to do this:

```
PreparedStatement preStmType = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE article_id = ?");
preStmType.setString(1, rsetArticle.getString(5));
preStmType.setInt(2, rsetArticle.getInt(1));
```

It does not seem to work. When I remove the argument for the FROM clause and use it only in the where, it works, but I would like to generate the FROM dynamically too.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't

Prepared statements supports data literals only.

Speaking of this particular case, why do you want to generate fieldlist dynamically? If you don't know what field you need - just select all and then pick one from the returned row

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Java?

How about trying this:

```
String qryStr = "SELECT * FROM "+rsetArticle.getString(5)+" "
qryStr =qryStr + "WHERE article_id = ?"

PreparedStatement preStmType = conn.prepareStatement(qryStr);
preStmType.setInt(1, rsetArticle.getInt(1));
```

Comment: I know i'm already doing that temporarily, but I'm looking for a better way to avoid sql injection.

Comment: You're trying to enable sql injection